# Написать регулярное выражение python помогите

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Столкнулся с вопросом в написании регулярного выражения. Как-то затрагивал их, но уже все вылетело из головы, пробовал взяться - ничего не вышло. Помогите написать, чтобы доставало данные в формате:

```
возраст = "первые две цифры"
рост = "вторые три цифры"
вес = "третьи две цифры"
тренировки ="последняя одна цифра'
```

> Вот входные данные :
> "trukhina287 37/168cm/    65/2TpeHupoBku/HeT FB anja01bez 29/156cm/65/3TpeH/re HeT nastya.ermakovaaa 23/170cm/62kr/2
> TPeHupoBKU/HeT rB

> Доставать должен примерно так :
> "**trukhina287** **37**/**168**cm/
> **65**/**2**TpeHupoBku/HeT FB   *что должен достать обвел жирным*.

Comment: Это всё что надо достать из входных данных? **nastya.ermakovaaa** не надо?

Comment: Приведите однозначные примеры короче, а для указанных в описании цифр смотреть ответ

Answer (score 2):

Вот нахождение нужных цифр (они будут в группах):

```
(\d{2})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/58r22

> "trukhina287 **37/168cm/ 65/2**TpeHupoBku/HeT FB anja01bez
> **29/156cm/65/3**TpeH/re HeT nastya.ermakovaaa **23/170cm/62kr/2**
> TPeHupoBKU/HeT rB

Что с именем непонятно - в описании его нет, но жирным выделено.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то что-то такое должно получиться:

```py
import re
sources_list = [
    'trukhina287 37/168cm/ 65/2TpeHupoBku/HeT FB',
    'anja01bez 29/156cm/65/3TpeH/re HeT',
    'nastya.ermakovaaa 23/170cm/62kr/2 TPeHupoBKU/HeT rB'
]

for elem in sources_list:
    age, height, weight, trainings = re.search(r'(\d+)/(\d+).*?/.*?(\d+).*?/(\d+)', elem).groups()
    print(
        f'возраст = {age}', 
        f'рост = {height}', 
        f'вес = {weight}', 
        f'тренировки = {trainings}', 
        sep='\n'
    )

# возраст = 37
# рост = 168
# вес = 65
# тренировки = 2
# возраст = 29
# рост = 156
# вес = 65
# тренировки = 3
# возраст = 23
# рост = 170
# вес = 62
# тренировки = 2
```